# Is there an easier way to do operations on ISO8601 formatted date from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to do some operations on some dates that have the ISO8601 dates from a .csv file, like a simple subtraction. I did it in a very long way that ultimately worked for just one operation, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it more easily, or that did not require so much work

The date in the .csv file are like this:

```
2022-10-04T00:16:09.700Z
```

I call the .csv with pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('earthquake_data.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
year,month,day = df.time.dt.year, df.time.dt.month, df.time.dt.day
t0 = date(year.values[-1], month.values[-1], day.values[-1])
t1 = date(year[0], month[0], day[0])
t2 = t1 - t0
```

data example:

```
                         time    dmin   latitude    status
0    2022-10-04T00:16:09.700Z     NaN  18.172667  reviewed
1    2022-10-03T23:49:59.984Z  1.3830   6.896400  reviewed
2    2022-10-03T23:03:58.220Z     NaN  19.201167  reviewed
3    2022-10-03T22:08:59.770Z  0.0566  17.971100  reviewed
4    2022-10-03T21:33:38.097Z  5.6570 -23.113000  reviewed
```

Comment: What operations do you need to do with your dataframe?

Comment: Mostly simple math operations, sum, subtraction

Comment: If you want to work with just the dates, you can floor datetime to the day; `df['time'].dt.floor("d")`.